# Octave: Specify diary file using string variable?

Tags: octave

I have the following statements to set the diary & diary file:

```
fnDiary = [ mfilename '.out.txt' ]
system(['rm -f ' fnDiary])
diary off; diary fnDiary
```

This doesn't work, since Octave thinks I want the diary file name to be "fnDiary".  Is there a way to specify the diary file using a string variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common error. Octave (and Matlab) treats arguments for a function outside () as string. Use this:

```
fnDiary = [ mfilename '.out.txt' ]
unlink (fnDiary)
diary off;
diary (fnDiary)
```

Comment: Gee, I never realized that Matlab did that too.  And yet, there it is, right in the documentation.  I much prefer your use of the unlink command over shelling out for an OS specific deletion command.  Thanks!